# Checkpointing in pytorch and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, checkpoint

What is in tensorflow, which is equal to the function of torch.utils.checkpoint?Please explain!!Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please answer tensorflow utility which is the same as torch.utils.checkpoint.Thanks in advance!!